# Select Box and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I change a message when I select different values from a select box using jquery.

```
<select name="myname">
   <option value="rahul" selected>Rahul</option>
   <option value="aisha">aisha</option>
</select>
```

If `rahul` is selected show a message `hello rahul` or if `aisha` is selected then show a message `hello aisha`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HjVxR/

```
$('[name="myname"]').change(function(){
   $('#message').html('hello ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[name="myname"]').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $('.message').html(selected);
});
```

Give the box you want to have the message in the class selected

Answer (score 0):

Give an Id to your select box like

```
<select id ="op" name="myname">
<option value="rahul" selected>Rahul</option>
<option value="aisha">aisha</option>
</select>
```

then u can use some thing like this

```
$('#op').change(function(){
alert("Hello " + $(this).val());
});
```